# Why is the image displayed blackish for the bit plane slicing program in Matlab?

Tags: matlab, image-processing

I was writing a code for bit plane slicing of an image in Matlab and got all the 8 images as blank . What could be the possible problem happening here . I tried converting the original image into uint8 format but it also didn't help . The code is as :

```
%BIT PLANE SLICING
clear all;
i=imread('C:\Users\divyansh dwivedi\Pictures\img1.jpg');
i=uint8(i);
i=imresize(i,[256,256]);
x=size(i);
z=zeros(x(1),x(2));
z=uint8(z);
imshow(i)
figure;
for j=1:8
    z=bitget(i,j);
    figure;
    imshow(z);
end
```

Comment: imshow(z,[]) suggested by Parag will map the range of values in the image to that of the display.  Stretching [0-1] to [0-255] so you can see it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I made a change in your code using the function `imagesc` to display your image , that will scale your image using the color range of your picture, and defining a color map (`colormap`), in this case `gray`

```
%BIT PLANE SLICING
clear all;
i=imread('C:\Users\divyansh dwivedi\Pictures\img1.jpg');
i=uint8(i);
i=imresize(i,[256,256]);
x=size(i);
z=zeros(x(1),x(2));
z=uint8(z);
imshow(i)
figure;
for j=1:8
    z=bitget(i,j);
    figure;

    % Using a function imagesc to scales the image to the image color range
    imagesc(z); colormap(gray);

end
```

You can have more information about the `imagesc` function and the color maps available at the MatLab documentation about [imagesc](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/imagesc.html) and [colormap](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/colormap.html).